# CMake - MacOS - BundleUtilities adds Python Interpreter to app and doesn't do fixup on it

Tags: python-3.x, macos, cmake, bundle

I'm using `cmake version 3.16.1` to add Python to my app bundle on the MacOS 10.15.1 Terminal. When I try to bundle a MacOS app, I'm getting a cmake error from BundleUtilities:

- The Python interpreter included in my cmake generated myApp.app/ release folder is linking to external libraries, that is, it is not getting fixed up by the Bundle Utilities.

Please let me know if I'm missing any important information.

NOTE: These are excerpts from a CMakeLists.txt that also builds several other plugins for our cross platform app. I've tried my best to narrow it down.

Python is installed from the `port` utility at `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python`, and python3.6 is is set to the default version.

`$ python3 --version` outputs `Python 3.6.9` on my Terminal

I'm trying to use `CMakeLists.txt` to add Python3 to my MacOS app bundle. I've copied some of the variables from `CMakeCache.txt` into the comments below, to show cmake found them.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(myApp)
#PYTHON_VERSION_NUMBER inherited from Makefile, e.g. "3.6"
#NOTE: Problem happens with and without "Interpreter" being specified
find_package(Python3 EXACT ${PYTHON_VERSION_NUMBER} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development Interpreter)
#Python3 include directory is '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m'
include_directories(AFTER SYSTEM ${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#$Python3_LIBRARY_DIRS is /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib
link_directories(${Python3_LIBRARY_DIRS})
#Python3_LIBRARIES is '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib'
target_link_libraries(myApp ${Python3_LIBRARIES})
```

At this point I am able to build and link several source files into executable files, some of them require Python, e.g. C code with Python.h and cython compiled source files.
I am able to install them into the app.

```
if(APPLE)
set(APPS "\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/myApp.app")
```

(...)

```
    INSTALL(CODE "
        include(BundleUtilities)
        fixup_bundle(\"${APPS}\" \"\" \"\")
        " COMPONENT Runtime)

    set(CPACK_BINARY_DRAGNDROP ON)
    include(CPack)
```

During the cmake output of fixup_bundle, it copies Python:

```
-- fixup_bundle: preparing...
-- fixup_bundle: copying...
(...)
-- 2/66: copying '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python'
```

... It fixes the Python library:

```
-- 35/66: fixing up '/Users/username/Projects/myApp/build/release/myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python'
```

Error output during cmake's `BundleUtilities` `verify_app` function. It is showing the Python interpreter was not fixed up.

```
-- executable file 2: /Users/username/Projects/myApp/build/release/myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
-- verified='0'
-- info='external prerequisites found:
f='/Users/username/Projects/myApp/build/release/myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python'
external_prereqs='/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python;/opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib;/opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib'
-- 
CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/BundleUtilities.cmake:1119 (message):
  error: verify_app failed
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/local/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/BundleUtilities.cmake:986 (verify_app)
  cmake_install.cmake:155 (fixup_bundle)
```

Check out the specific file the BundleUtilities output complains about, showing it is linking to external resources.

```
% otool -L build/release/myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
build/release/myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1670.10.0)
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python (compatibility version 3.6.0, current version 3.6.0)
  /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.5.0)
  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.0.0)
```

fixup_bundle copied the python framework, including the python library and interpreter. Only the library was fixed up. Then Bundle Utilities found that the interpreter was linking to external resources and correctly produced the error.

This leads to my questions:

- Why wasn't it fixed by bundle utilities?
- Is there anything I can do to work around this?
- Maybe I'm not using cmake correctly?

The file specified in the error is the Python interpreter. I'm not sure if it's required. Some C code uses Python.h to call the Python interpreter (perhaps a sub question - is this Python interpreter binary required?)

```
$ file /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

```
$ /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:05:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Where as this is a lib, which BundleUtilities copies and fixes for app deployment.

```
$ file /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python 
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Aside: I'm going to create a small project that will either reproduce this, or show that perhaps something in our larger project is messing things up. If it reproduces this, it may be a misunderstanding of how to use cmake, or worse.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is [known](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2017-March/065140.html) for a while.

Note the `Python.app` comes under `Resources`, which is somewhat unusual. If we look into `function(copy_resolved_framework_into_bundle ...)`, there is a blind resources copying:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${resolved_resources}" "${resolved_embedded_resources}")
```

This explains how the `Python` executable arrives into a bundle, while not being a dependency!

Then `function(verify_bundle_prerequisites ...)` calls `verify_app` on the resulting bundle and discovers `Python.app` for the first time after copying - thus unpatched.

At first, I was thinking of removing Python executable, which [reportedly](https://github.com/inviwo/inviwo/issues/240#issuecomment-421376813) resolves the problem. Later I thought it might be not that bad having a bundled Python interpreter. We can handle it with the following modification:

```
--- a/BundleUtilities.cmake 2019-12-28 02:10:43.000000000 +0100
+++ b/BundleUtilities.cmake 2019-12-28 09:39:26.000000000 +0100
@@ -982,6 +984,13 @@
     message(STATUS "fixup_bundle: cleaning up...")
     clear_bundle_keys(keys)

+    # Recursively discover and fix all subsequent executables.
+    get_bundle_all_executables("${bundle}" file_list)
+    list(REMOVE_ITEM file_list "${app}" ${CFG_IGNORE_ITEM})
+    list(LENGTH file_list nexecutables)
+    if (${nexecutables} GREATER 0)
+      list(GET file_list 0 f)
+      message(STATUS "fixup_bundle: fixing newly discovered executable ${f}...")
+      fixup_bundle("${f}" "" "${dirs}" IGNORE_ITEM ${CFG_IGNORE_ITEM} ${app})
+    endif()
+
     message(STATUS "fixup_bundle: verifying...")
     verify_app("${app}" IGNORE_ITEM "${CFG_IGNORE_ITEM}")
   else()
```

With this mod, CPack finishes successfully:

```
-- fixup_bundle: done
CPack: Create package
CPack: - package: ****.dmg generated.
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out after the holidays. When I verify it works, I'll mark this as the answer.

I've made a tiny example with a C program, calling Python.h, which reproduces the error. If I can, I'll make it available in a public repository and file it as a bug with cmake.

Comment: Validated using the test project with a C program that uses Python.h and with our bigger project.

`-- fixup_bundle: cleaning up...
-- fixup_bundle: fixing newly discovered executable /Users/myname/Projects/MyApp/build/release/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python...`

Comment: `otool -L` shows it's been fixed
`build/release/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python:
(...)
 @executable_path/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python (compatibility version 3.6.0, current version 3.6.0)
 @executable_path/../Frameworks/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.5.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.0.0)`

Comment: Also cmake 3.16.2 was released. Confirmed the problem still exists and was fixed by the above, proposed solution.

Will file bug with cmake with example code in a public repository.

Comment: Bug report for cmake:

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/20165

Comment: NOTE: The python interpreter is not actually required by a c program calling Python.h

`rm ./HelloPython.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
./HelloPython.app/Contents/MacOS/HelloPython                                                                     
Today is Thu Jan  2 14:08:51 2020
`

Comment: Oops! This actually doesn't work. Inside the app, look at the Python interpreter, and note that it's @exectuable_path is wrong.

```otool -L Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python 

 @executable_path/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python (compatibility version 3.6.0, current version 3.6.0)
 @executable_path/../Frameworks/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.5.0)```

Comment: The relative path to the Python Lib and the libintil are wrong.

I was able to just run it on my Terminal from inside my app with the error:

```./Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/andrew/Projects/momd/build/release/momd.app/Contents/PlugIns/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      
```

Comment: Please see the bug report for a simple HelloPython.app which builds like this. You can reproduce the bug by running the Python Interpreter like I did in the comment above.

Comment: Here's further evidence. It copies some libs into the Python.app inside of the Python.Frameworks, but it should actually reference a relative path to the myApp.app's Frameworks folder (through ../../../ ... until it reaches it)

```ls /Users/username/Projects/myApp/build/release/momd.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/Frameworks/
libiconv.2.dylib libintl.8.dylib
```